# mongodb avg in aggregation of array element

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following collection structure

```
{
   "_id": {
     "d_timestamp": NumberLong(1429949699),
     "d_isostamp": ISODate("2015-04-25T08:14:59.0Z")
   },
   "XBT-USD-cpx-okc": [
   {
       "buySpread": -1.80081
   }
```

I run the following aggregation

```
$spreadName ='XBT-USD-stp-nex';
$pipe = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            '_id.d_isostamp' => array(
                '$gt' => $start, '$lt' => $end
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'sellSpread' =>'$'.$spreadName.'.sellSpread',
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'isodate' => array(
                    '$minute' => '$_id.d_isostamp'
                )
            ),
            'rsell_spread' => array(
                '$avg' => '$sellSpread'
            ),
        )
    ),
);

$out = $collection->aggregate($pipe ,$options);
```

and I get as a result the value 0 for `rsell_spread` whereas if I run a `$max` for instance instead of an `$avg` in the `$group` , I get an accurate value for `rsell_spread` , w/ the following structure

```
{
  "_id": {
     "isodate": ISODate("2015-04-25T08:00:58.0Z")
  },
  "rsell_spread": [
     -4.49996▼
  ]
}
```

So I have two questions :

1/ How come does the `$avg` function does not work?

2/ How can I can a result not in an array when I use `$max` for example (just a regular number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) group accumulator operator does work, it's only that in your case it is being applied to an element in an array and thus gives the "incorrect" result.
2. When you use the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) group accumulator operator, it returns the the highest value that results from applying an expression to each document in a group of documents, thus in your example it returned the maximum array.

To demonstrate this, consider adding a few sample documents to a test collection in mongoshell:

```
db.test.insert([
{
    "_id" : {
        "d_timestamp" : NumberLong(1429949699),
        "d_isostamp" : ISODate("2015-04-25T08:14:59.000Z")
    },
    "XBT-USD-stp-nex" : [ 
        {
            "sellSpread" : -1.80081
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "d_timestamp" : NumberLong(1429949710),
        "d_isostamp" : ISODate("2015-04-25T08:15:10.000Z")
    },
    "XBT-USD-stp-nex" : [ 
        {
            "sellSpread" : -1.80079
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "d_timestamp" : NumberLong(1429949720),
        "d_isostamp" : ISODate("2015-04-25T08:15:20.000Z")
    },
    "XBT-USD-stp-nex" : [ 
        {
            "sellSpread" : -1.80083
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : {
        "d_timestamp" : NumberLong(1429949730),
        "d_isostamp" : ISODate("2015-04-25T08:15:30.000Z")
    },
    "XBT-USD-stp-nex" : [ 
        {
            "sellSpread" : -1.80087
        }
    ]
}
])
```

Now, replicating the same operation above in mongoshell:

```
var spreadName = "XBT-USD-stp-nex",
    start = new Date(2015, 3, 25),
    end = new Date(2015, 3, 26);
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id.d_isostamp": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "sellSpread": "$"+spreadName+".sellSpread"
        }
    }/*,<--- deliberately omitted the $unwind stage from the pipeline to replicate the current pipeline
    {
        "$unwind": "$sellSpread"
    }*/,
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "isodate": { "$minute": "$_id.d_isostamp"}
            },
            "rsell_spread": {
                "$avg": "$sellSpread"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "isodate" : 15
            },
            "rsell_spread" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "isodate" : 14
            },
            "rsell_spread" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The solution is to include an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator pipeline stage after the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) step, this will deconstruct the `XBT-USD-stp-nex` array field from the input documents and outputs a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value. This will then make it possible for the [**`$avg`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) group accumulator operator to work.

Including this will give the aggregation result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "isodate" : 15
            },
            "rsell_spread" : -1.80083
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "isodate" : 14
            },
            "rsell_spread" : -1.80081
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So your final working aggregation in PHP should be:

```
$spreadName ='XBT-USD-stp-nex';
$pipe = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            '_id.d_isostamp' => array(
                '$gt' => $start, '$lt' => $end
            )
        )
    ),    
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'sellSpread' =>'$'.$spreadName.'.sellSpread',
        )
    ),
    array('$unwind' => '$sellSpread'),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array(
                'isodate' => array(
                    '$minute' => '$_id.d_isostamp'
                )
            ),
            'rsell_spread' => array(
                '$avg' => '$sellSpread'
            ),
        )
    ),
);

$out = $collection->aggregate($pipe ,$options);
```